# Validate insert +1 or not depending of phone value regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression, so I want to add +1 when number does not start with it. And if it starts with 1 it should display as +1 then `(###)-###-####`

But it is throwing `1+1-(###)-###-####` when the number starts with 1

Expression:

```
 var formattedShipperPhone = Regex.Replace(model.Shipper.ContactPhone, @"(?:\+1[\- /]?)?([2-9]\d{2})[\- /]?([2-9]\d{2})[\- /]?(\d{4})", "+1-($1)-$2-$3");
```

How can I validate the 1 if it already has it or not?

Comment: Have you considered using `string.StartsWith` rather than regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are matching `+1` and if there is no plus sign you will also not match the 1 so it is untouched and stays in the replacement.

The + can be optional, and you don't have to escape the `\-`

Example

```
var strings = new List<string>() {
    "+1-288-388-4441",
    "+1288-388-4442",
    "1288-388-4443",
    "288-388-4444",
};
            
foreach (var s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        Regex.Replace(
            s, 
            @"(?:\+?1[- /]?)?([2-9]\d{2})[- /]?([2-9]\d{2})[- /]?(\d{4})", 
            "+1-($1)-$2-$3")
        );
}
```

Output

```
+1-(288)-388-4441
+1-(288)-388-4442
+1-(288)-388-4443
+1-(288)-388-4444
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like use `.*` in regex, but in this example you can try

```
".*([2-9]\d{2})[\- /]?([2-9]\d{2})[\- /]?(\d{4})"
```

and get

```
"+1-($1)-$2-$3"
```

In this case you will always delete what is before (###)-###-#### and just add +1